# What is a secondary school graduate called?

Tags: american-english, terminology, british-english, transatlantic-differences

I think *graduate* indicates only a university graduate in British English, but in American English can it perhaps also suggest a high-school graduate as well?

Could anyone tell me something about that?

Comment: We simply say “high school graduate”.

Comment: @Dan Bron is it an American way of calling that or British way?

Comment: In UK we don't have "high school" as a general type of school, although some have that in their name, for example "Stamford High School". So "high school graduate" is an AmE term. In UK students who are at secondary school "leave school". For example "Pete left school at age 18 with three A-levels". But "Peter **graduated** from Cambridge University with a First".

Comment: Just to reiterate what @WeatherVane said, there is no "graduation" ceremony for (secondary) school leavers in the UK. In fact, in Scotland, final exam results don't usually arrive until August, but school finishes in June/July, so you don't even know what you've achieved/passed until AFTER you've left school.

Comment: @Angyang American, sorry for not being clear in my first comment. In the US we do have a graduating ceremony for HS. With the weird hats and the diplomas and everything.

Comment: FYI, In the USA (AmE), "leave school" would suggest that the person dropped out, i.e. left school without graduating/completing the course of study.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes.  Moreover, there is no concept of ‘drop-out’ in the British system.  Governments have in the past thirty years tried to ‘encourage’ children to stay on till 18 or at least continue till 18.  However, in the U.K. education is much more messy than in the US.  There are many secondary (high) schools that provide only up to the age of 16, at which point those that continue in formal schooling may go on to what are called ‘sixth form colleges, catering for 16-18 toward-olds, or to ‘further education’ or ‘tertiary’ colleges, providing academic and vocational courses for 16-adult.

Comment: In Scotland, “Jimmy”.

Comment: I have no epistemological reason for saying this, but American English, as a general rule, seems to me to make more use of descriptors, than we do in Britain. It also seems more inclined to insist upon uniformity in the naming of social furniture. Both of those tendencies would appear to be evident here.

Comment: @WS2 “Social furniture”! I love it!

Answer (score 1):

I speak AmE, but I have encountered the term ***school-leaver*** or ***school leaver*** in BrE and AuE writings.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/school-leaver) defines *school leaver*:

> School leavers are young people who have just left school, because they have completed their time there.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/school-leaver) defines *school-leaver*:

> a young person who is about to leave or has just left secondary school

Comment: So every day at 3:30 the school-leavers get on the bus for their trip home??

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, see the "ha, ha" comment above, perhaps you could add that "leaving school" is someone who *finishes* studying or abandons school to enter employment.

Answer (score 0):

We (UK) don't "graduate" from secondary (high) school as there is no simple pass or fail result.

However, the trend of "graduation" at all states of education is spreading in the UK.

> Little Ladybirds nursery in Stockton-on-Tees in the North East of
>   England has offered graduations since 2011. ...
>   Kindergarten graduation has been an event in the US since at least the 1960s,

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-28399266

Do four-year-olds need a graduation ceremony?
Justin Parkinson, BBC News Magazine, 23 July 2014

Scottish schools do, however, award a dux to one pupil (and maybe a semi-dux to a second) but this is not usually solely based on exam results.